# Trouble nesting DIVs in zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

Im using foundation to develop a site. I have 6 main rows of content. Each main row consists of a 12 column div, with two 6 column divs nested inside. 
Each extra main row I add gets a little wider each time. I assume I am nesting the divs incorrectly. Could anyone point out my mistake? I'll add an example of my code below.

```
   <div class="row"><!--START 12 ROW-->  
    <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p class="info"><span class="infoHead" >Header</span></br><img class="line" src="images/line.png" alt=""></p>
    <div class="row"><!--START 6 ROW-->
    <div class="large-6 columns">
            <p class="info">Lots of text</br></br><span class="infoSpan">Some more text</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
            <p><img border="0" src="images/image.jpg" alt=""></p>
            <p class="btt">Back to top</p>
    </div>
    </div><!--END 6 ROW-->
</div><!--END 12 ROW-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem the instant I posted this question.

I wasnt closing the first '', so I was adding each extra main row to the original 12 column DIV.